# Group null and empty string together

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, group-by, string

I want to group the NULL and empty fields in a column together .

I tried the below script

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN test IS NULL OR test= ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE test
  END as 'test' 
from firm 
group by test
```

If we are having the values NULL,'',Test1,Test2 in the column test,the above query will create two groups with NULL values as below.

```
1 NULL

2 NULL

3 Test1

4 Test2
```

What I want is a grouping shown below.

```
1 NULL or ''

2 Test1

3 Test2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Try this hope this helps you**

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN test IS NULL OR test= ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE test
  END as 'test' 
from firm 
group by CASE WHEN test IS NULL OR test = '' THEN '' ELSE test END
```

OR

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN test IS NULL OR test= ''
    THEN ''
    ELSE test
  END as 'test' 
from firm 
group by isnull(test, '')
```

Comment: The second one won't compile.

Answer (score 8):

Your CASE is reinventing COALESCE:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(test, '') as test
from firm 
group by COALESCE(test, '')
```

or simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  COALESCE(test, '') as test
from firm
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
Select Case when IsNull(test,'') = '' Then '' Else test End as test 
From Firm
Group By IsNull(test,'')
```